# Join on non unique column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I have two tables in DB and I want to select and join some data from these table.

The first table has some customers:

| customer | id |
| --- | --- |
| Dave | 1 |
| Tom | 2 |

The second table has a list of products and a column that indicates which customer bought that Product:

| id | product | isin | customer id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PC | XV452889 | 1 |
| 2 | phone | VN865232 | 2 |
| 3 | laptop | PL201325 | 1 |

I tried INNER JOIN in order to get as output a table that lists for each product that have been bought, who was its customer.

Desired output:

| id | product | isin | customer id | customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PC | XV452889 | 1 | Dave |
| 2 | phone | VN865232 | 2 | Tom |
| 3 | laptop | PL201325 | 1 | Dave |

I tried inner join but the answer is empty, its like you cant join two table on a non-unique column. it has been two days I try to solve it.

```
select table2.product, table2.customer_id 
from table2 
   inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.customer_id;
```

Hers is the query I am running on similar tables (allocations table is equivalent to the second table of product above and orders is equivalents to customer table):

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *I tried INNER JOIN in order to get* So please, post your inner join, because it should do the work.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you have tried.

Comment: Given the sample data, an inner join (e.g. as in the answer given by Mureinik) [most certainly works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fe66f916e6a25f5e308382bac1425954)

Comment: You are joining on the wrong columns - you can't compare an integer (table1.id) with a string (table2.customer) - that query should result in an error "*operator does not exist: integer = text*"

Comment: If you just look at your data and try to do `table1.id = table2.customer` manually on the sheet of parer you'll see that there's no rows where this condition is true. And you'll easily find the correct condition since there's not so much column to brute force. Really, looks like very little time was spent on the homework.

Comment: It looks like you simplified your [mre] too much so it no longer reproduces the problem. Given your screenshot (which, BTW, would have been better posted as code formatted text), it looks like `orders.id` and `allocations.id` refer to different, disjunct ids, so maybe you should join on `orders.id = allocation.order_id` instead of `orders.id = allocations.id`.

Comment: Thank you mark for your response!
allocations.id is the foreign key that connect both table as opposed to allocations.order_id which is the unique key of allocations table.

It is quite wierd that when I run the same query in postgres terminal I get a response with a table full of info. but when running it in the code as above , 'results' isnot define and this the server return a code 500 error..

Comment: Thnak you all for your help and replies!
i hope its now more understanble .. i simply cant figure out why it works on the terminal directly, and not in the code where i get a response that  'results' is not define..

Answer (score 1):

You can join the `customer.id` on `product.customer_id`:

```sql
SELECT p.*, c.customer
FROM   products p
JOIN   customer c on p.customer_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR ANSWERS about he join!!!
I found the error in the query, it was missing ',' after orders.instructions...
too long queries ):